# Delete any row from DataGridView as well as from database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, delete-row

I want to delete the selected row from DataGridView as well as the database. My code works only for the first row, for every other row it gives exception "Index was out of Range".

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        string itemId;
        if (dgPartyDetails.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
        {
            int selectedrowindex = dgPartyDetails.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            try
            {
                DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgPartyDetails.SelectedRows[selectedrowindex];
                if (selectedRow.Selected == true)
                {
                    dgPartyDetails.Rows.RemoveAt(selectedrowindex);
                    itemId = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[0].Value);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblParty WHERE Id=" + itemId + "";
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: share aspx code and in which event are you writing above code?

Comment: It is for Windows Forms and not aspx. I have written it on button click event

Comment: what is the exception that you receive? if any...

Comment: Try `dgPartyDetails.CurrentCell.RowIndex;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you removed the DataGridRow before obtaining it's value.

```
dgPartyDetails.Rows.RemoveAt(selectedrowindex);
itemId = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[0].Value);
```

Reversing the order of these statement would fix your problem.

```
itemId = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[0].Value);
dgPartyDetails.Rows.RemoveAt(selectedrowindex);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can try sqldatasource. for example:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsJur" runat="server" 
           ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NilaiConnectionString %>" 
           DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Jurusan] WHERE [Kd_Jurusan] = @Kd_Jurusan" 
           InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Jurusan] ([Jurusan]) VALUES (@Jurusan)" 
           SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Jurusan]" 
           UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Jurusan] SET [Jurusan] = @Jurusan WHERE [Kd_Jurusan] = @Kd_Jurusan">
           <DeleteParameters>
               <asp:Parameter Name="Kd_Jurusan" Type="Int32" />
           </DeleteParameters>
           <InsertParameters>
               <asp:FormParameter FormField="tbJurusan" Name="Jurusan" />
           </InsertParameters>
           <UpdateParameters>
               <asp:Parameter Name="Jurusan" Type="String" />
               <asp:Parameter Name="Kd_Jurusan" Type="Int32" />
           </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>`
```

and then u can use Gridview(I think similar to datagrigview). for example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvJurusan" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
     AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Kd_Jurusan"DataSourceID="sdsJur">
     <Columns>
         <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Kd_Jurusan" HeaderText="Kd_Jurusan" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Kd_Jurusan" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Jurusan" HeaderText="Jurusan" SortExpression="Jurusan" />
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>`
```

hope it usefull

Comment: It is not for asp .net. I am doing that in windows forms using C#! It is "DataGridView" and not "GridView". Thankyou anyway! :)